# A collection of ranges

Tags: c#, range, collections

Imagine a scenario where, using xml, the user is able to specify ranges in a flexible manner, using any combination of "gte", "gt", "lte", "lt" or "eq".

Here are some examples

```
<rangeElement gte="0" lt="5" ... />
<rangeElement gt="3" lte="7" ... />
<rangeElement eq="5" ... />
<rangeElement gt="10.5" ... />
```

Now what I need is two classes, Range and RangeCollection, that can deal with these.

The Range class might look something like this:

```
public class Range
{
   public LowerBoundInclusive { get; set; }
   public LowerBoundExclusive { get; set; }
   public UpperBoundInclusive { get; set; }
   public UpperBoundExclusive { get; set; }
   public object Data { get; set; }

   public Range(XElement xmlElement)
   {
      ....
   }
}
```

The RangeCollection class should have some basic way of sorting its ranges, detecting overlaps and returning a corresponding range given a value.

I've had a play with this but things quickly get fiendishly complex. Has anyone else seen a implementation of this, or want to give it a shot?

BTW. I know there are similar threads that tackle ranges but they do not adequately deal with the difference between "less-than-or-equal" and "less-than".

Comment: your examples did not show up.  Please review?

Comment: what is value supposed to be given your example xx>=0 && xx<5 is this accurate? Then what is xx? are you looking for the first match in the collection?

Comment: Show some client code of the api your thinking that might help me undersatdn your intentions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is [interval tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree). It is not hard to find [implementation in C#](http://www.koders.com/csharp/fidAECCF1ACC07C26A4B6836EE7DF8C4EB0F19129C8.aspx?s=mdef%3Acompute) and modify it to make it suitable to your needs. I don't see any problems with "<=" or just "<" relations.

Comment: Yes that does look like what I need. The C5 library has a thing called an "IntervalHeap"... I wonder if that is the same thing.